# RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused

Tags: rpc, sunrpc

I am trying to do a simple Sun RPC program which is a phonebook. It sends and receives commands like adding or removing someone to server and server responds back with a message.

When I run the both programs(Server and Client) after the first command it closes unexpectedly and got this error

```
RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
```

I already checked and `rpcbind` and `portmap` is installed.

And here is my `rpcinfo` output:

```
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
 553523285    1    udp       0.0.0.0.3.222          -          superuser
 553523285    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.3.223          -          superuser
```

The server procedures run normal, I put printf in server side and it shows the server is running but cannot send message back to the client!

Comment: If `rpcinfo` also errors try running `/etc/init.d/rpcbind start`